# Автоматизация тестирования веб-приложения на Angular 6. Что использовать Protractor или Selenide?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-automation, angular5, protractor

Появилась необходимость автоматизировать проверку всех форм в веб-приложении.
В проекте используется *Angular 6*.

*Back*, a точнее все *API* методы будут проверяться тестами на *Java*. 
Встал вопрос, как автоматизировать проверку front-a, а точнее самих форм.

Тесты планируется писать на двух уровнях:

1. Покрыть все формы тестами, которые будут проверять корректность наполнения страницы, что все поля отображаются в нужном состоянии и при вводе определенных данных переводятся в нужное состояние, а также проверка, что при нажатии на кнопки будут переданы нужные запросы в back. Т.е. в этом случае сценарии выполняться не будут, будет просто проверяться отдельная страница.
2. Несколько сквозных сценариев пользователя, т.е. успешные сценарии, которые будут проверять всю систему в целом.

Для этих целей выбираем между двумя стеками технологий:

1. e2e, Protractor
2. Selenide + Java

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. *Protractor* - использует тот же движок *WebDriver*, что и *Selenide*, или это другое?
2. Кто имел дело с *Protractor* - удобно ли писать тесты именно для *Angular*.

Хотелось бы принять наиболее правильное решение с учетом на долгосрочную перспективу. 
Т.е. что удобнее поддерживать, с каким стеком технологий будет меньше возни с самим UI (определение элементов страницы, ожидания).

Заранее благодарю за любые ответы. 
А также буду благодарна за ссылки на статьи или может книжки по данной теме.

Answer (score 0):

Ну Protractor как бы и предназначен для Angular.

Моё мнение что ЯП и инструменты автоматизации должны быть независимыми от стека продукта.
Учитывая что API вы будете покрывать на Java - то и хороши бы и фронт на нём же. Будет один общий фреймворк в котом можно будет спокойно реализовывать любые полезные служебные классы/методы, которые смогут пригодиться как на фронте, так и на бекенде.
Всё должно быть универсальным и унифицированным :)